# What does 'conver' means

Tags: meaning, american-english

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

I saw the word on Remarks by President Biden and President Xi of the People’s Republic of China Before Virtual Meeting
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/vAdJr.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Biden was about to say "conversation". Then he intended to have "candid" put before the word. So he stopped halfway (conver...), and then continued "candid conversation".

Comment: Now I see, thank you

Answer (score 1):

The word in the picture is not "conver" it's "conver-"  implying he was going to say something like "conversation" but stopped half way through.

Comment: Now I see, thank you

Comment: It's more common to use a dash than a hyphen where a word is broken off, but the two are often substituted/confused (and the punctuation in the image looks weird and wrong so the author may have intended a dash) https://www.sussex.ac.uk/informatics/punctuation/hyphenanddash/dash

Comment: @StuartF I don't think it is more common in typed text.  Most people don't have a dash key on their keyboard. The sample here is a strange combination of dashes as parenthesis and hyphens as dashes

Comment: True on a typewriter, but most word processors will do dashes, often automatically. It's not clear the source of the extract but in formal, published works, a dash is recommended by most authorities.